# Switching to Base Internationaliztion

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

My app is currently localized for English and Japanese, with seperate storyboards for each.  I want to switch to base localization so that I only have to maintain a single storyboard.  I've checked the "Use Base Internationalization" box in the project's info tab and chosen the English iPhone and iPad storyboards for the base.

I assume I should delete the Japanese iPhone and iPad storyboards I had previously used, but I don't see an option to delete them when right-clicking on their files in the file inspector.  Should I delete these old storyboards, and, if so, how?

** Edit **

Changing the 'Main Interface' shown in the screenshot doesn't allow me to delete the Japanese storyboard.  It's hard to tell which storyboard to select in the dropdown because its width is more narrow than the storyboard names, but that's  a separate issue.

[image]

Comment: Looks like xcode 5 dp - still under NDA afaik

Comment: Why is everyone so anxious about the NDA. If Apple does not like it, then they will remove the stuff. Relax, I doubt the "fruit" is not going to hunt you down if it is not the new iPhone or what...

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: It does look like that, but the question isn't specific to Xcode 5, it applies to 6.4.3 also.

Comment: I agree, that's why i didn't bash or downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning and reloading, I was able to remove the Japanese storyboards by clicking on the - in the project settings:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/02/automating-strings-extraction-from-storyboards-for-localization/) drives you through the process step-by-step. This is how it worked for me:

1. Remove all localizations and leave only the base.
2. Ensure that the localized files were moved from the project directory (in Finder)
3. Add the localizations one-by-one
4. The localized strings are extracted from the storyboard only when the localization is created. The Tutorial above provides a script that can help you keeping the localized files up to date if the storyboard is changed.

In your case, you will have to merge the existing translations into the new files but I suppose it is not a huge deal compared to the gain with using a single file.

For reference, the process is described in this official tutorial too: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried changing the project settings as suggested (see update in the original post) but I still can't delete the Japanese storyboards.

Comment: @MichaelMangold I figured out the way this has to be really done. Look at the updated answer. Sorry for the confusion.